# Retrieve and update status of lineitems of type TrueView

Tags: java, double-click-advertising

We're currently building a tool for pausing / enabling our advertising campaigns with regards to certain weather conditions. For that purpose, we first check the weather and then need to retrieve all of our "campaigns" i.e. our insertion orders out of our managers (using the DoubleClick Bid Manager API), in order to update their statuses (or not).

We didn't find a way to do that with the API so we thought about pausing / enabling all of the line items composing the insertion order, which would result in the same effect at the end.

We managed to do that using the downloadlineitems and then the uploadlineitems functions (https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/v1/lineitems/downloadlineitems) BUT the problem is that the TrueView line items aren't retrieved with the downloadlineitems function (and consequently, we can't re-upload them using the uploadlineitems function). Is there some parameters we've missed?

Thanks a lot in advance to anyone that could enlighten me with this issue.

Kind regards,
Phillippe